# React zodResolver put constraint date should be greater than now

Tags: reactjs, validation, zod

I am using the zod library to validate my react forms. I am using this schema.

```
import * as zod from "zod";

export const appointmentSchema = zod.object({
  title: zod.string().nonempty("Please enter a title"),
  description: zod.string(),
  scheduledDate: zod.date()
});

export type appointmentFormData = zod.infer<typeof appointmentSchema>;
```

Is there a way to add validation to datetime to throw an error if datetime submitted is greater than date.now?

Answer (score 2):

You should try like this :

```js
import * as zod from "zod";

export const appointmentSchema = zod.object({
  title: zod.string().nonempty("Please enter a title"),
  description: zod.string(),
  scheduledDate: zod
  .instanceof(Date, { message: 'The Date field is required.' })
  .refine((date) => {
      return date < new Date(Date.now());
    }, "The date must be before today"),
});

export type appointmentFormData = zod.infer<typeof appointmentSchema>;
```

You will find the documentation of zod at the link below : https://github.com/colinhacks/zod

Comment: Hello Julien! I see you are new to StackOverflow. When answering a question, try to give an explanation as well rather than just posting a code snippet without explanation :)

Comment: What happens if Zod is server-side and my client-side UTC differs from server ? Because there is some cases where the client's date can be on the future according server where it shouldn't. Should I send client's UTC on server for comparing ?

Answer (score 0):

A little late but just in case someone prefers a more hands off approach

```js
const utcCheck = (kind: "min" | "max", offset = 0) => ({
    kind: kind,
    get value() {
        return Date.now() + offset;
    }
});
```

use as

```
zod.date()._addCheck(utcCheck("max"))
```